# How to make iPhone as a dlna server?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dlna

Thanks to all in advance.

I am trying to make iPhone as DLNA server but I can't find any library.

So, any one can know how to make iPhone as a DLNA server?

Any link for DLNA library?

Comment: Hi @Chetan Bhalara did you get the solution? I too want to implement the same

Comment: https://github.com/MediaBrowser/MediaBrowser.Plugins/tree/master/ThirdParty/UPnP